# Bullets in pygame project not deleting when game restarts

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to Python and coding in general, so I'm following this beginner [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jO6qQDNa2UY&ab_channel=TechWithTim) to make a two-player space invaders type game in `pygame`.

All of the code for the mechanics in the game work correctly. However, whenever I try to restart the game by calling the `main()` function, everything resets except for the bullets (which means that bullets fired in the previous game will hit the players in the next game)

Here is the main function:

```py
def main():
    Player_One_Hitbox = pygame.Rect(WIDTH/4-SPACESHIP_WIDTH, HEIGHT/2-SPACESHIP_HEIGHT, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    Player_Two_Hitbox = pygame.Rect(3*WIDTH/4-SPACESHIP_WIDTH, HEIGHT/2-SPACESHIP_HEIGHT, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    Player_One_Bullets = []
    Player_Two_Bullets = []
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    global Player_One_Health
    global Player_Two_Health
    Player_One_Health = 20
    Player_Two_Health = 20
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
        #DO STUFF HERE
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and len(Player_One_Bullets) < NUM_BULLETS:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(Player_One_Hitbox.x, Player_One_Hitbox.y + Player_One_Hitbox.height//2, 20, 5)
                    Player_One_Bullets.append(bullet)
                if event.key == pygame.K_KP0 and len(Player_Two_Bullets) < NUM_BULLETS:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(Player_Two_Hitbox.x, Player_Two_Hitbox.y + Player_Two_Hitbox.height//2, 20, 5)
                    Player_Two_Bullets.append(bullet)
            if event.type == PLAYER_ONE_HIT:
                Player_One_Health -= 1
            if event.type == PLAYER_TWO_HIT:
                Player_Two_Health -= 1
        winner_text = ""
        if Player_One_Health <= 0:
           winner_text = "Player One Wins!"
        if Player_Two_Health <= 0:
            winner_text = "Player Two Wins!"
        if winner_text != "":
            draw_winner(winner_text, Player_One_Bullets, Player_Two_Bullets)
            break

        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        Player_One_Movement(keys_pressed, Player_One_Hitbox)
        Player_Two_Movement(keys_pressed, Player_Two_Hitbox)

        handle_bullets(Player_One_Bullets, Player_Two_Bullets, Player_One_Hitbox, Player_Two_Hitbox)

        draw_window(Player_One_Hitbox, Player_Two_Hitbox, Player_One_Bullets, Player_Two_Bullets, Player_One_Health, Player_Two_Health)
    main()
```

Why does emptying out the bullets list using `Player_One_Bullets = []` and `Player_Two_Bullets = []` not despawn the bullets? Is this a `pygame` thing or a Python thing?

Full code:

```py
from PIL import Image
import random
import pygame
pygame.font.init()

#Pygame Parameters config
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1600,800
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Battle Stars")
SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT = 55,55

BORDER = pygame.Rect(WIDTH//2 - 5, 0, 10, HEIGHT)

HEALTH_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans',30)
WINNER_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('conicsans', 200)

FPS = 240

PLAYER_ONE_HIT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
PLAYER_TWO_HIT = pygame.USEREVENT + 2

LOW_VEL = 1
MED_VEL = 5
HIGH_VEL = 15

RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

NUM_BULLETS = 3

Player_One_Health = 20
Player_Two_Health = 20

Backdrop = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\Garrett\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Backdrop.png").convert()


#Load Player Sprites from Sprite Sheet
Sprite_Sheet = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Garrett\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Spaceships.png")
def Load_Sprite(row,column):
    sprite_x_coord = ((35*(column-1))+(10*(column-1)))+5
    sprite_y_coord = ((35*(row-1))+(10*(row-1)))+5
    crop_rectangle = (sprite_x_coord, sprite_y_coord, sprite_x_coord + 35, sprite_y_coord + 35)
    image = Sprite_Sheet.crop(crop_rectangle)
    return image

Player_One = Load_Sprite(random.randint(1,24), random.randint(1,24))
Player_Two = Load_Sprite(random.randint(1,24), random.randint(1,24))

Player_One_Image = pygame.image.fromstring(Player_One.tobytes(), Player_One.size, Player_One.mode).convert()
Player_Two_Image = pygame.image.fromstring(Player_Two.tobytes(), Player_Two.size, Player_Two.mode).convert()

Player_One_Sprite = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(Player_One_Image, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)), 270)
Player_Two_Sprite = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(Player_Two_Image, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)), 90)

def draw_window(Player_One_Hitbox, Player_Two_Hitbox, Player_One_Bullets, Player_Two_Bullets, Player_One_Health, Player_Two_Health):
    WIN.blit(Backdrop, (0,0))
    WIN.blit(Backdrop, (853,0))
    WIN.blit(Backdrop, (853,480))
    WIN.blit(Backdrop, (0,480))

    Player_One_Health_Text = HEALTH_FONT.render("Health:" + str(Player_One_Health), 1, (255, 255, 255))
    Player_Two_Health_Text = HEALTH_FONT.render("Health:" + str(Player_Two_Health), 1, (255, 255, 255))
    WIN.blit(Player_One_Health_Text, (10,20))
    WIN.blit(Player_Two_Health_Text, (WIDTH-Player_Two_Health_Text.get_width(), 20))
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (255,255,255),BORDER)
    WIN.blit(Player_One_Sprite, (Player_One_Hitbox.x, Player_One_Hitbox.y))
    WIN.blit(Player_Two_Sprite, (Player_Two_Hitbox.x, Player_Two_Hitbox.y))

    for bullet in Player_One_Bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, RED, bullet)
    for bullet in Player_Two_Bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, GREEN, bullet)
    pygame.display.update()

def Player_One_Movement(keys_pressed, Player_One_Hitbox):
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and Player_One_Hitbox.y < HEIGHT-50-MED_VEL:
        Player_One_Hitbox.y += MED_VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and Player_One_Hitbox.y > MED_VEL:
        Player_One_Hitbox.y -= MED_VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and Player_One_Hitbox.x > 0:
        Player_One_Hitbox.x -= MED_VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and Player_One_Hitbox.x < (WIDTH/2)-SPACESHIP_WIDTH:
        Player_One_Hitbox.x += MED_VEL

def Player_Two_Movement(keys_pressed, Player_Two_Hitbox):
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] and Player_Two_Hitbox.y < HEIGHT-50-MED_VEL:
        Player_Two_Hitbox.y += MED_VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP] and Player_Two_Hitbox.y > MED_VEL:
        Player_Two_Hitbox.y -= MED_VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and Player_Two_Hitbox.x > (WIDTH/2):
        Player_Two_Hitbox.x -= MED_VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and Player_Two_Hitbox.x < WIDTH-SPACESHIP_WIDTH:
        Player_Two_Hitbox.x += MED_VEL

def handle_bullets(Player_One_Bullets, Player_Two_Bullets, Player_One_Hitbox, Player_Two_Hitbox):
    for bullets in Player_One_Bullets:
        bullets.x += HIGH_VEL
        if Player_Two_Hitbox.colliderect(bullets):
            Player_One_Bullets.remove(bullets)
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(PLAYER_TWO_HIT))
        elif bullets.x > WIDTH:
            Player_One_Bullets.remove(bullets)
        for Green_Bullets in Player_Two_Bullets:
            if Green_Bullets.colliderect(bullets):
                try:
                    Player_Two_Bullets.remove(Green_Bullets)
                    Player_One_Bullets.remove(bullets)
                except:
                    pass

    for bullets in Player_Two_Bullets:
        bullets.x -= HIGH_VEL
        if Player_One_Hitbox.colliderect(bullets):
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(PLAYER_ONE_HIT))
            Player_Two_Bullets.remove(bullets)
        elif bullets.x < 0:
            Player_Two_Bullets.remove(bullets)

def draw_winner(text, Player_One_Bullets, Player_Two_Bullets):
    draw_text = WINNER_FONT.render(text, 1, (255,255, 0))
    WIN.blit(draw_text, (WIDTH//2 - draw_text.get_width()/2, HEIGHT/2 - draw_text.get_height()/2))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(1000)

def main():
    Player_One_Hitbox = pygame.Rect(WIDTH/4-SPACESHIP_WIDTH, HEIGHT/2-SPACESHIP_HEIGHT, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    Player_Two_Hitbox = pygame.Rect(3*WIDTH/4-SPACESHIP_WIDTH, HEIGHT/2-SPACESHIP_HEIGHT, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    Player_One_Bullets = []
    Player_Two_Bullets = []
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    global Player_One_Health
    global Player_Two_Health
    Player_One_Health = 20
    Player_Two_Health = 20
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
        #DO STUFF HERE
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and len(Player_One_Bullets) < NUM_BULLETS:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(Player_One_Hitbox.x, Player_One_Hitbox.y + Player_One_Hitbox.height//2, 20, 5)
                    Player_One_Bullets.append(bullet)
                if event.key == pygame.K_KP0 and len(Player_Two_Bullets) < NUM_BULLETS:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(Player_Two_Hitbox.x, Player_Two_Hitbox.y + Player_Two_Hitbox.height//2, 20, 5)
                    Player_Two_Bullets.append(bullet)
            if event.type == PLAYER_ONE_HIT:
                Player_One_Health -= 1
            if event.type == PLAYER_TWO_HIT:
                Player_Two_Health -= 1
        winner_text = ""
        if Player_One_Health <= 0:
           winner_text = "Player One Wins!"
        if Player_Two_Health <= 0:
            winner_text = "Player Two Wins!"
        if winner_text != "":
            draw_winner(winner_text, Player_One_Bullets, Player_Two_Bullets)
            break

        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        Player_One_Movement(keys_pressed, Player_One_Hitbox)
        Player_Two_Movement(keys_pressed, Player_Two_Hitbox)

        handle_bullets(Player_One_Bullets, Player_Two_Bullets, Player_One_Hitbox, Player_Two_Hitbox)

        draw_window(Player_One_Hitbox, Player_Two_Hitbox, Player_One_Bullets, Player_Two_Bullets, Player_One_Health, Player_Two_Health)
    main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `main()` recursively, but call it in a loop:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    while run:
        # [...]

    # main() <--- DELETE 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    while True:
        main()
```